# The notation $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$

Tags: group-theory, notation

Let $\alpha$ be a real number. I'm studying group theory from the notes of my brother (I'm 16) and I often jump into the notation $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, which, however, is defined nowhere through the text. I've thought of the smallest subgroup of the additive group of the real field containing $\alpha$ and all of its powers (with positive and negative exponents), but I'm not that sure. Also, is there any special motivation for this notation (whatever it may mean)?

Comment: So very relevant that you're 16 and you're studying your brother's book.

Comment: It means you're adjoining $\alpha$ to the ring $\Bbb Z$: $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ consists of all polynomials in $\alpha$ with integer coefficients. For example, $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ consists of all elements $a+b\sqrt 2$ with $a,b$ integers. The reason is that higher degree polynomials "don't get anything else" than $\sqrt 2$ or $2$: any power $(\sqrt 2)^n$ can be reduced using that $(\sqrt 2)^2=2$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Do you mean that it is isomorphic (as a group) to the additive group of the ring of polynomials in one variable over the integers? I'm not convinced, because if $\alpha$ is, for instance, the golden ratio then it seems to me that I should obtain something like the subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ consisting of numbers of the form $\frac{a+b\sqrt{5}}{2}$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Y/N?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen you edit. I meant ring (singular) of polynomials. But OK, now I think to get it: it is the set of all real numbers of the form $f(\alpha)$ such that $f$ is an integer polynomial in one variable, right?

Comment: by the way you better study from Lang's book which is certainly much much better than your bro's notes

Comment: @000 That is a matter of opinion and not worded very neutrally.

Comment: @GitGud Maybe he is implying he is dumber because he is 16? Or he is just needing an ego boost?

Comment: @Daniel: I don't think there is any question about it, and no one would deny it.

Comment: @000 given you haven't seen the (possibly brilliant) lecture notes his brother is studying from, I think there *is* question about it. Some of the lecture notes I've used in the past have been written by truly brilliant teachers, and have been better than any text book.

Comment: I would also object to having someone doing algebra for the first time studying out of Lang's book.

Comment: I would second @Mike's opinion. Although it is certainly a wonderful and rigorous text, you don't throw a graduate algebra text at someone trying to understand it for the first time.

Comment: @Daniel the difference being that it is generally accepted that Lang's book is among the best elementary algebra books, which cannot be said about your notes written by "truly brilliant teachers" (if you are claiming that they are better than Lang's book, then you are probably the only one expressing this opinion). But I am certainly interested in taking a look on your lecture notes that "have been better than any text book" (in your opinion). Get Lang, the sooner the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually stands for all polynomials in α with integer coefficients.

Answer (score 6):

The notation $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ means the set of all expressions of the form
$$
b_0+b_1\alpha+b_2\alpha^2+\dots+b_n\alpha^n
$$
with $b_0,b_1,\dots,b_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ (and whatever non-negative integer $n$), so the “polynomial expressions in $\alpha$” with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$”.

When studying abstract algebra it is convenient to think to polynomials $b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+\dots+b_nx^n$ as simply formal expressions that don't denote a number. They can be summed and multiplied with the usual rules forming what's called a *ring* whenever the set of coefficients is a ring itself: for example the integers or the reals; they're denoted by $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

When $f=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+\dots+b_nx^n$ is a polynomial with real coefficients (in particular they may be integers) and $\alpha$ is a fixed real number, we can define
$$
f(\alpha)=b_0+b_1\alpha+b_2\alpha^2+\dots+b_n\alpha^n
$$
This has the pleasant properties that
$$
f(\alpha)+g(\alpha)=(f+g)(\alpha),\quad
f(\alpha)g(\alpha)=(fg)(\alpha)
$$
where $f+g$ and $fg$ denote the “formal sum and product” in the ring of (abstract) polynomials.

Thus $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is just the set of all numbers that you get by computing  $f(\alpha)$ for all polynomials with integer coefficients.

A real number is *algebraic* if there exists a nonzero polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. It is *transcendental* otherwise.

So $\sqrt{2}$ is algebraic because $f(\sqrt{2})=0$ where $f=x^2-2$. Giving examples of transcendental numbers is not easy; better, it's not easy to prove that a given real number is transcendental. In 1880 it was proved by Lindemann that $\pi$ is transcendental; together with a result by Wantzel, this finally established that squaring the circle with ruler and compass is not possible.

You may as well use $\mathbb{Q}$ for the coefficients; in this case one can see where the big difference between algebraic and transcendental number is: if $\alpha$ is algebraic, then all numbers
$$
b_0+b_1\alpha+b_2\alpha^2+\dots+b_n\alpha^n\ne0
$$
in $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ have their inverse in $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ again! This is not true for transcendental numbers: if one of the coefficients $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$ is non zero and $\alpha$ is transcendental, then the inverse of $b_0+b_1\alpha+b_2\alpha^2+\dots+b_n\alpha^n$ is *not* in $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$.

For instance, $1+2\sqrt{2}\ne0$ and
$$
(1+2\sqrt{2})^{-1}=\frac{1}{1+2\sqrt{2}}=
\frac{-1+2\sqrt{2}}{(-1+2\sqrt{2})(1+2\sqrt{2})}=
\frac{-1+2\sqrt{2}}{7}=-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{2}{7}\sqrt{2}
$$
which is again in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Conversely, $(1+\pi)^{-1}$ cannot be represented as a polynomial expression with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, because $\pi$ is transcendental.